# Is there a simple way to daemon-ify a simple task?

Tags: ssh, daemon, background-process

I ssh into a server than start a job (for instance rsync), then I just want to be able to log out from the server and let the job run its course. But if I just do `rsync ... &` I think it's still connected to the tty in some way, and that the job dies when the tty goes away when logging out. Is there any (easy) way to disconnect the process from the tty to be able to log out without the process terminating?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nohup rsync ... &
```

Seems to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7):

you could start it in a [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)

Comment: +1 also to using screen. It's simply to use and once you get used to it, you'll never want to be without it. I would consider it one the most valuable tools I use in the Unix world.

Comment: Thanks but n00b as I am I don't know how. Example cmdline might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setsid` and redirect handles 1 and 2 to `/dev/null`.

e.g.

```
setsid \
  perl -e 'for ( my $i = 0; 1; $i++ ) { $0 = "forever $i"; sleep( 1 ); }' \
  1>/dev/null \
  2>/dev/null
```

Without `setsid` and a trailing ampersand the command `ps ax` shows:

```
13526 pts/4    S      0:00 forever 11
```

With `setsid` and no trailing ampersand the command `ps ax` shows:

```
13520 ?        Ss     0:00 forever 68
```

...indicating no attached TTY.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux (Ubuntu at least) you can use `start-stop-daemon`

If all you want is to start a process and leave it running, you can use

```
at now
```

Answer (score 0):

Debian and Ubuntu have a package called [daemon](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=daemon) which seems to be part of the [libslack](http://www.libslack.org/daemon/) project.